# When to use. ProtoRPC or REST

Tags: api, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

I primarily deal with REST json APIs at my work. So I am familiar with them. But for my own project I am trying out app engine as I believe it is a great fit.

I had already started writing my logic in python (using ferris), and in reading more on app engine I came across protorpc and cloud endpoints. But in most of the examples I have read, they seem to be doing the same just as I would do in a rest api. Make a request with json, and get a json response back. Or an error.

The main difference I see, is that in rest, the endpoints are based around a resource. And the HTTP verbs around them such as GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. Where as in RPC, each request would have it's own endpoint rather than be based around a resource or model.

Both are requested with, and respond with json. So I think I am failing to see the benefit of using Google endpoints. Do they offer some other kind of benefit? I could maybe see better analytics tracking with endpoints. But wouldn't I still need to the use post http verb for modifying content?

Would any of this change if I was using certain frameworks? Like django. Although I am currently testing out Ferris which has a messaging system that deals with protorpc. Although, I have not been able to rest or yet.

So what am I missing? What are the benefits of endpoints over just making my object methods handle a json request. Do socket connections play into this at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do both by using `endpoints` to make a RESTful API.

`protorpc`/`endpoints` doesn't magically make your API RESTful. *You* have to make your API RESTful within the `endpoints` framework, which uses `protorpc`.

The benefits of using `endpoints` is that you can get a lot of the authentication work done easily (assuming you're going to use Google accounts), the serialization/deserialization is done for you, your client libraries can be generated for you, and more than just a Javascript client can be supported. If these things sound good, `endpoints` may be right for you. If these things don't apply, then maybe be more direct and use RequestHandlers yourself.

I was able to make a simple API using `endpoints`. It has 3 main resources: records, datasets and moves. A `Record` object is the smallest unit of data. The `Dataset` object is a group of records. And the `Move` object represents the event of a `Dataset` changing location.
My RESTful URIs look like this:

```
GET  /records       # Get list of records
GET  /records/<id>  # Get single record
POST /records       # Create records

GET  /datasets      # Get list of datasets
GET  /datasets/<id> # Get single dataset
POST /datasets      # Create dataset

GET  /moves         # Get list of moves
GET  /moves/<id>    # Get single move
POST /moves         # Create move
```

With this I can create data, organize it and move it around. I was able to do this completely within the `endpoints` framework on App Engine and it is RESTful.

Comment: This was pretty much the path I went and worked best. I did however end up not using app engine ultimately and just started using compute so I could use python 3 and have more control over the host system. And now am trying to make that even better with docker. But this is the answer and how I would do it if I used appengine again.